# For every category I want to make numeric calculations

Tags: r

I want to add a column in r to  calculate the difference of scores for every equal characters in the same column (e.g:names)

I tried to group the data using `group_by` function in `dplyr` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What does "didn't work" mean exactly? Did you get an error message?

Comment: For e.g:      col 1: James, Andrew, James, Sonya, Catherine, Sonya                 col2:83,84,87,40,50,55......for every same name I want score difference

Comment: @HusHas Please don't include critical data/code in comments; instead edit your question. It's also best to include your expected output for the sample data you give. That often helps us understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(score_diff = c(0, diff(score)))
## A tibble: 6 x 3
## Groups:   name [4]
#  name      score score_diff
#  <fct>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 James        83          0
#2 Andrew       84          0
#3 James        87          4
#4 Sonya        40          0
#5 Catherine    50          0
#6 Sonya        55         15
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
    name = c("James", "Andrew", "James", "Sonya", "Catherine", "Sonya"),
    score = c(83,84,87,40,50,55))
```